# weather json not showing

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to get weather info via wunderground JSON data using volley , the problem is he not show any data , string and int , when i make debug i get response from url but no information displays

```
package imo.meteoiraq;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RequestQueue rq;
TextView humdityDesc;

    String humdity;


     String url="http://api.wunderground.com/api/XXXXX/conditions/forecast/forecast10day/hourly/lang:AR/q/33.237575299999996,44.3384822.json";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rq= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        humdityDesc= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humdid);

        sendjsonrequest();
    }
public void  sendjsonrequest(){
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                JSONObject stationsJO = response.getJSONObject("current_observation");
                humdity = stationsJO.getString("weather");
                 humdityDesc.setText(humdity);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    rq.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

    private String getDate(long  timeStamp){
        try{
            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
            return sdf.format(netDate);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            return "xx";
        }
    }



}
```

[data json](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=802a5ec8ca1fd181759b9ed7224bed5e)

Comment: did the `onSuccess()` called with the expected Resonse `JSONObject response` ?

Comment: `onErrorResponse` is empty... Put a log statement in there

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 am not add onSuccess() you can check my code

Comment: @cricket_007 check out https://f.top4top.net/p_561pa2vr1.png

Comment: Okay, what about it? Does that setText get called?

Comment: humdityDesc @cricket_007